# Object from Kotlin Multiplatform (KMM) instantiated inside Swift function. Function ends its scope. Who deallocates the object?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

If I instantiate an object from Kotlin Multiplatform inside a Swift function on iOS, when the function finishes its scope, who deallocates the Kotlin object? iOS or the Kotlin garbage collector?

I know that Kotlin Native has its own Garbage Collector. But what is puzzling me is how memory management works when you have Kotlin Native objects inside Swift/ObjC and ObjC objects inside Kotlin Native.

Comment: [Kotlin/Native memory management](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/05/kotlin-native-memory-management-update/)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, Kotlin's GC.

Kotlin native objects present to iOS like other Objc objects. They will get memory management calls like other Objc objects. When nothing from iOS is holding a reference to a KN object, the KN runtime will collect it, although exactly when that will happen is more complex. Objects aren't necessarily deallocated right away. Also, there are now two major memory models, and I would imagine they work s

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear as I thought. If I instantiate an object from Kotlin Native inside a Swift function, who deals with the GC when Swift function finishes its scope?